# convert multi-categorical column into two category in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below.

df:

```
ID      tag              
1       pandas
2       numpy
3       matplotlib
4       pandas
5       pandas
6       sns
7       sklearn
8       sklearn
9       pandas
10      pandas
```

to the above df, I would like to add a column named tag_binary. Which will whether it is pandas or not.

Expected output:

```
ID      tag            tag_binary         
1       pandas         pandas
2       numpy          non_pandas
3       matplotlib     non_pandas
4       pandas         pandas
5       pandas         pandas
6       sns            non_pandas
7       sklearn        non_pandas
8       sklearn        non_pandas
9       pandas         pandas
10      pandas         pandas
```

I tried the below code using a dictionary and map function. It worked fine. But I am wondering is there any easier way without creating this complete dictionary.

```
d = {'pandas':'pandas', 'numpy':'non_pandas', 'matplotlib':'non_pandas',
    'sns':'non_pandas', 'sklearn':'non_pandas'}
df["tag_binary"] = df['tag'].map(d)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `where` with an equality check to keep `'pandas'` and fill everything else with `'non_pandas'`.

```
df['tag_binary'] = df['tag'].where(df['tag'].eq('pandas'), 'non_pandas')

   ID         tag    tag_binary
0   1      pandas        pandas
1   2       numpy    non_pandas
2   3  matplotlib    non_pandas
3   4      pandas        pandas
4   5      pandas        pandas
5   6         sns    non_pandas
6   7     sklearn    non_pandas
7   8     sklearn    non_pandas
8   9      pandas        pandas
9  10      pandas        pandas
```

---

If you want something a little more flexible, so you can also map specific values to some label, then you can leverage the fact that for keys not in your `dict`, `map` returns `NaN`. So only specify mappings you care about and then `fillna` to deal with **every** other case.

```
# Could be more general like {'pandas': 'pandas', 'geopandas': 'pandas'}
d = {'pandas': 'pandas'} 
df['pandas_binary'] = df['tag'].map(d).fillna('non_pandas')
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use apply

```
def is_pandas(name):
    if name == 'pandas':
        return 'pandas'#or True
    return 'non_pandas' # or Fales 

df['tag_binary'] = df['tag'].apply(lambda x: is_pandas(x))
```

Comment: You could also remove the lambda: `df['tag_binary'] = df['tag'].apply(is_pandas)`

Answer (score 3):

If specifically needing "Categorical Data", to assign some ordering hierarchy, ensuring that only these values are permitted in the column, or simply reducing the amount of space, we can create a [`CategoricalDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html) make the conversion with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill the `NaN` values introduced when converting values that are not contained within the Categorical:

```
cat_dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(['pandas', 'non_pandas'])
df['tag_binary'] = df['tag'].astype(cat_dtype).fillna('non_pandas')
```

`df`:

```
   ID         tag  tag_binary
0   1      pandas      pandas
1   2       numpy  non_pandas
2   3  matplotlib  non_pandas
3   4      pandas      pandas
4   5      pandas      pandas
5   6         sns  non_pandas
6   7     sklearn  non_pandas
7   8     sklearn  non_pandas
8   9      pandas      pandas
9  10      pandas      pandas
```

---

Setup Used:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'tag': ['pandas', 'numpy', 'matplotlib', 'pandas', 'pandas', 'sns',
            'sklearn', 'sklearn', 'pandas', 'pandas']
})
```